# How do I use thumbnail_size for a user photo which is uploaded as usermeta

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have created a field in user profile edit page which allows user to upload their profile photo. The information gets saved in `wp_usermeta` table under `user_profile_image` key.

No Gravatar will be used in the application, photos uploaded by user himself from admin will be used as his/her profile photo.

I have different thumbnail sizes defined in my theme and I can see the correct thumbnail size uploaded fine.

But I don't know how to apply a `thumbnail_size` with get_the_author_meta function like we do for post thumbnails. Is there any way to do it?

Currently I am retrieving user's photo like this:

`$profile_picture = get_the_author_meta( 'user_profile_image', $current_author->ID );`

But additionally I need to apply the following thumbnail size:
`add_image_size( 'blog-author-thumbnail', 450, 675, true); // constrain width to 450`, which I have no idea how!

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does `$profile_picture` contain? html? the ID? array? url?

Comment: could you `var_dump($profile_picture);` for us?

Comment: It is the url of the image. `var_dump()` output is:
`http://vagrant.local/content/uploads/2018/01/Bird-in-Flight-11.jpg`

Comment: So you get the URL

Comment: I'll try my best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving an image id by the URL is common when developing plugins etc.

And i guess that you can do it this way as well.

```
// retrieves the attachment ID from the file URL - put this into functions.php
function pippin_get_image_id($image_url) {
    global $wpdb;
    $attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url )); 
    return $attachment[0]; 
}

// Next part is for displaying the image in your template etc.

// set the image url
// $image_url = 'http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/14/image_name.jpg';
// or in your case : 
$image_url = $profile_picture;

// store the image ID in a var
$image_id = pippin_get_image_id($image_url);

// retrieve the thumbnail size of our image - you can change the size - so you could use 'blog-author-thumbnail'
$image_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'thumbnail');

// to display the image
echo $image_thumb[0];
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code but the returned value is the same as original attachment, not the thumbnail. I need to return `http://vagrant.local/content/uploads/2018/01/Bird-in-Flight-11-450x675.jpg` but it is returning `http://vagrant.local/content/uploads/2018/01/Bird-in-Flight-11.jpg`

Comment: Did you change "thumbnail" to "blog-author-thumbnail" in the image size?

Comment: Yes, I did exactly as you said

`$image_id = yrc_get_image_id_by_url( $profile_picture );
 $image_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'blog-author-thumbnail' );
 return $image_thumb[0];`

Comment: Hi, I probably figured it out. `wp_get_attachment_image_src` deals with in-built image sizes like `thumbnail`, `large` etc. So I passed an array instead of the thumbnail name and now it works! Here is what I did: `$image_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, array( 450, 675 ) );` But thank you so much for guiding me to the right way... :)

Comment: No problem m8 - I would appreciate it if you were to accept the answer :)

Comment: also - weird that it didsn't accept your image size - According to the codex "Accepts any valid image size" as well as arrays - Have you regenerated your thumbnails after you created the image size?

Comment: I uploaded the image only after I added the image size.